# Xampp Installation Server Issue

Tags: ubuntu, installation, xampp

I Installed XAMPP Linux 1.8.2 and tried to start server(/opt/lampp/lampp start) which is responding like this

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.2-2...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
XAMPP:  Another FTP daemon is already running.
```

and i can't open localhost,xampp,phpmyadmin etc.

I already have older version of xampp in opt directory which i have renamed to lampp-bk and newer version is like lampp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to port conflict.you can solve  this by doing this process 
first stop apach2 if it running by following command

sudo service apache2 stop

then try starting it by command

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

if does not resolve change ur port no by this way

open  httpd.conf in.lampp search for line listen 80

Change it to

listen 0.0.0.0:2145

and to httpd-ssl.conf change listen 443 to

listen 0.0.0.0:16443

Then open /opt/lampp/lampp

Check for line 80 to 2145
and line 443 to 16443

Then start lamp again

it will success

in browser open localhost;2145

Comment: htypd-ssl.conf can be found in /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

Comment: for your phpmyadmin problem just check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426501/how-to-solve-the-xampp-1-7-7-phpmyadmin-mysql-error-2002-in-ubuntu

Comment: or else try using adminer for further steps installation and usuage check this post. http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/using-adminer-to-manage-your-databases

Comment: have you tried this posthttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426501/how-to-solve-the-xampp-1-7-7-phpmyadmin-mysql-error-2002-in-ubuntu?

Comment: go .. let try this sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp
sudo chown -hR nobody /opt/lampp
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp and even stop your mysql if it running b this command sudo service mysql stop

Comment: is there any version mysql seems running in your linux? have you checked this

Comment: netstat -tln and check for line like this tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

Comment: what about your netstat -tln says?

Comment: your output already mysql is running .. you should need to stop ..then  you start it will succeed ..or change your port for mysql too

Comment: i hope this post will solve your problem http://chanakaudaya.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/solution-for-xampp-server-mysql-service-not-starting-on-port-3306-error/ on error revert back

Comment: check this too http://silentlyrun.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-change-apache-n-mysql-port-for.html

Comment: you should it /opt/lampp/ inside. some where, i dont have a linux pc in my hand so i cant help you right now

Comment: may be the location is  /opt/lampp/bin/mysql something like this

Comment: In the old lampp i stopped the service and in the new lampp started the service . and i got response like this .
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.2-2...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.

Comment: after that i tried click on phpmyadmin but now it says like this phpMyAdmin - Error

Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser. and still mysql database is deactivated in xampp

Comment: This is the current error " phpMyAdmin - Error Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser" ans also status of mysql database is deactivated in xampp

Comment: flush your browser cookies and try again in different browser to flush use alt+ctrl+del and press ok clear everything

Comment: Already tried clearing the cache etc.still same. But in xampp also it says like mysqldabase as deactivated. I have deleted and trying to install once again. i will let u know wat happens. Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to kill processes that are running on these ports, if it says that apache is already running it means that you have another daemon running on port 80
to see which process running on port 80 execute `sudo netstat -tunap | grep :80` you need to see the source IP on port 80 and not the destination. you can kill these process with `sudo kill -s 9 pid` replace pid with the right process id
if you have problem with ssl you need to change the port 80 with 443