# PhpMyAdmin Access Denied #2002 Ubuntu, Lampp ( Xampp For ubuntu )

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

After Installing lampp ( xampp for linux ), i got some xampp new security exception. For that I changed the http-xampp.conf file as follows

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After that I got the access denied issue which shows me as follows,

```
Error
MySQL said: Documentation

#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). 

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

I already tried a lot of things from ubuntu forums but unable to solve it. As I am new to ubuntu I can't get how these things work. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Solve the XAMPP 1.7.7 - PHPMyAdmin - MySQL Error #2002 in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426501/how-to-solve-the-xampp-1-7-7-phpmyadmin-mysql-error-2002-in-ubuntu)

Comment: When i tried mysql stop, it showed me command not found. Should I again install mysql even after i installed the xampp

Comment: try to stop mysql server: `/etc/init.d/mysql stop` and then `/opt/lampp/lampp restart` that should do the trick. If it is not working let me know. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

so i think you should do like :

create a file phpmyadmin.conf in /etc/apache2/conf.d/

write this to that file:

`

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
        php_value include_path .
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
    AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

`

Answer (score -1):

Change the port number of mysql. My default it will be 3306, that port may be in use, so change the port number to 3307 or some other number