# #2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

Tags: mysql

I am currently getting this error on `xampp(1.7.4)`.
I was working on php and then i just restarted my computer and then when i open `phpmyadmin`, It shows me this error.
Don't know what happen.
what i have to do now?
I have search a lot & `reinstall` the `xampp 1.7.4` .but nothing helps?

It says,
Error

MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try cleaning your browser cookies and see it helps to resolve this issue, before even trying any configuration changes..

Comment: I searched many questions on stackoverflow and this is the only answer that solved my problem..

Comment: Try this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426501/how-to-solve-the-xampp-1-7-7-phpmyadmin-mysql-error-2002-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I tried incognito mode (equivalent to removing cookies) but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

When you got error with `#2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)`

The url already changed to `/phpmyadmin/error.php?lang=en&dir=ltr&type=Error&error=%232002+-+The+server+is+not+responding+%28or+the+local+MySQL+server%27s+socket+is+not+correctly+configured%29`
and will not redirect back.

So you must check the url is `/phpmyadmin/`

For my problem is `install php56 on redhat6` and I forgot to set default socket 、port and host. I fixed it ,but refresh my browser it won't work, and the problem is this.

Answer (score -2):

```
go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc 
edit host 
add 
127.0.0.1 localhost
and restart server
refresh
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382251/2002-the-server-is-not-responding-or-the-local-mysql-servers-socket-is-not/48382252#48382252