# I install XAMPP on ubuntu , i have error opening them know

Tags: php, ubuntu

I did install XAMPP on ubuntu , and it was working fine , but today when I installed nessus , I figure out that i can't enter to phpmyadmin it give me this error:

```
#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

Comment: id suggest you refer to the following post 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426501/how-to-solve-the-xampp-1-7-7-phpmyadmin-mysql-error-2002-in-ubuntu

Comment: i tray it but no success

Answer (score 0):

In your xampppath\apache\conf\extra open file httpd-xampp.conf

Find:

```
# Close XAMPP sites here
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Replace With

```
# Close XAMPP sites here
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Add the lines:

/*Edited*/

at the end of the file 000-ispconfig.conf file in the sites-enabled folder of your apache configuration add

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and restart xampp, and all should be well

Comment: i get this when i startmysql 'XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
'

Comment: try  sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf

sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/var/mysql

sudo chown -hR root/opt/lampp

Comment: chown -hR root/opt/lampp -> chown: missing operand after `root/opt/lampp'
Try `chown --help' for more information.

Comment: sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
    sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/var/mysql -R
    sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart

Comment: i get the same error `Access to the requested directory is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".`

Comment: `You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` i have this error