# Error #2002 in localhost/phpmyadmin. in Ubuntu using XAMPP

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

After starting XAMPP on my Ubuntu 12.04.5 on KDE interface and trying to open phpmyadmin on the localhost I am getting this error:

> 2002 - No such file or directory The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
>
> Connection for
> controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

However I tried the suggestion in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426501/how-to-solve-the-xampp-1-7-7-phpmyadmin-mysql-error-2002-in-ubuntu) ([How to Solve the XAMPP 1.7.7 - PHPMyAdmin - MySQL Error #2002 in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426501/how-to-solve-the-xampp-1-7-7-phpmyadmin-mysql-error-2002-in-ubuntu)) but I have no "mysql" file in the "init.d" folder. I hope this can be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt-get --reinstall install mysql-server
```

solved it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. You might consider marking your response as the accepted answer here so that others can quickly see that it's resolved.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch stackoverflow won't let me accept my own answer until 2 days after the answer was placed :)