# MySQL Database stopped in XAMPP-1.8.3.4 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

MySQL already running, but  when open http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ I get error like this :

> #2002 - Connection refused The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

when I try run from command line with sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start, I get the message like this :

> XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
>   XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.

I have checked in `ps -aux | grep mysqld`

I get message like this:

> ahmadso+  7118  0.0  0.0  15948  2220 pts/6    S+   09:23   0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld

when I try sudo service mysql stop
I get message like this :

> stop: Unknown instance:

I use Ubuntu operating system, I have tried to uninstall and reinstall xampp, but does not resolve the issue.

please help me.

Comment: Do you have another mysql running on the machine? Try doing `which mysqld` and see which paths you get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Solve the XAMPP 1.7.7 - PHPMyAdmin - MySQL Error #2002 in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426501/how-to-solve-the-xampp-1-7-7-phpmyadmin-mysql-error-2002-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you for responding, I find mysql in / usr / sbin / mysqld then what should I do. @ytpillai

Comment: Try stopping mysql using the mysqld command itself (`path_to_mysqld stop`)

Comment: The response you get when running `ps` only shows the grep process running, it doesn't show the actual mysqld process running. This suggests that the MySQL daemon might not actually be running. Check the MySQL error log for hints.

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping all XAMPP Services and then start them again:

Stop

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service mysql stop
```

Start

```
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: thank you for answering, I have tried your way but it does not solve the problem. when I try sudo service mysql stop I get message like this 
stop: Unknown instance:  @jonathan-s

Comment: Go to `phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` and tell me what's the value of this: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']`

Comment: @AhmadSob can you log in from the terminal?